# Increment a number in a text string G00001 in excel

Tags: excel, vba, text, excel-formula

I am using this formula:="G"&TEXT(RIGHT(A2,5)+1,"00000")
which is not working?
Can any one help me on this?

Comment: try: ="G"&TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,5))+1,"00000")

Comment: Thanks for your response
But, it is still not working with this formula as well

Comment: i've tested, it worked (your initial formula worked fine also for me), please provide dataset example and check that your work in automatic calculation mode/

Comment: @BhanuPrakash What is value in `A2` cell. Post some sample data to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Set a *Custom* cell format for A2 as `"G"00000`
2. Enter the number 1 in cell A2. (The cell will show *G00001*)
3. In A3 enter this formula, `=A+1`. (The cell will show *G00002*)

Does that solve your problem?